# create a date range based on min & max dates in a group

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in the following format: the dates here are the same, but in my real data they differ.

```
+----------------------------------+-----+
|DATE_AGG                          |USER |
+----------------------------------+-----+
|[                                 |Julia|
|"2010-01-01",                     |     |
|"2022-08-23"                      |     |
|]                                 |     |
|[                                 |Jon  |
|"2010-01-01",                     |     |
|"2022-08-23"                      |     |
|]                                 |     |
|[                                 |Amina|
|"2010-01-01",                     |     |
|"2022-08-23"                      |     |
|]                                 |     |
+----------------------------------+-----+
```

---

```
SELECT ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(dt_from, dt_to) as date_agg, user
FROM (
  VALUES
    ('2010-01-01', '2022-08-23', 'Julia'),
    ('2010-01-01', '2022-08-23', 'Jon'),
    ('2010-01-01', '2022-08-23', 'Amina')
       ) t(dt_from, dt_to, user)
```

---

I'd like to "explode/unnest" the `date_agg` column into a date range per `User`

I know how do this for a single range, but I wonder if there is a way I can do this in SQL? (my lazy brain is reaching for a UDF in Python..!)

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, '-' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL)
          , DATEADD(DAY, +1, CURRENT_DATE())
          ) AS dt
FROM TABLE (GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 9999))
```

my output would be as follows:

```
           date   user
0    2010-01-01  Amina
1    2010-01-02  Amina
2    2010-01-03  Amina
3    2010-01-04  Amina
4    2010-01-05  Amina
...         ...    ...
4613 2022-08-19  Julia
4614 2022-08-20  Julia
4615 2022-08-21  Julia
4616 2022-08-22  Julia
4617 2022-08-23  Julia
```

Comment: "I choose a lazy person to do a hard job. Because a lazy person will find an easy way to do it.", maybe you should listen to your brain

Comment: even so, I'd like to see some of the SQL chops from of the experts here @HoneyBadger if noone answers, I'll do it in Python and post my answer here :)

Comment: I would create a calendar table (many examples to be found), then it's just a matter of joining the calendar with your table

Comment: @HoneyBadger ah then I could cross join the users and join it back to my original table, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way

```
with cte as       
(select user,
        get(date_agg,0)::date as start_date, 
        datediff(day,get(date_agg,0)::date,get(date_agg,1)::date) as day_count
 from t)

select user, dateadd('day',b.index-1,start_date) as dates
from cte a, lateral split_to_table(repeat('.',day_count), '.') b
```

The idea is to figure out the range of days (N) between start and end date for each user. Then you can create as many rows for each user by generating a string of length N and splitting it to rows. When split to rows, you'll have an index column from `split_to_table` that you can add to start_date to compute all the dates for the range.

Comment: This is pretty cool -> where did you see this Phil or did you create yourself?

Comment: @AdrianWhite Myself, but I won't be surprised if you find something similar elsewhre

Comment: Awesome technique ...  on large datasets way more effecient than table_generator approach. Well done!